# Cordova Longpress doesn't work on iOS (but does work on Android)

Tags: cordova

I'm using Cordova 9.0.1. Longpressing works without problems on Android but when I deploy my app on iOS 13.1.3 the longpress gesture doesn't work.
What do I have to do to get the longpress gesture working on iOS?

Comment: You might need this [npm cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix).

Comment: @ColdCerberus : That plugin seems to be intend to supress long-press abilities and not enable them

Comment: No, it suppresses the new default behavior (or may there are many behaviors depending on the version) of iOS responding to a longpress. For example, Apple , for some reason, decided that it's nice to show a magnifying glass when longpressing the webview on iOS9. This one will fix it for you. Otherwise it is not a "longpress fix". It also fixes the issue on `-webkit-user-select: none;` not working on iOS.